# Anchor View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, anchor-view

I saw a reference about **Anchor View** in Android. If possible please provide an example with the explanation. I think it's related to some view group.

Comment: anchor? what anchor? what do you mean?

Comment: I saw the question in a site. But I did not get any proper explanation.

Comment: No no. I think it's related to some view groups.

Comment: Everything ui related is a view group.  What site? Please give references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchor View can be easily understood with the help of example below

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/value_animator_subjectb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="?android:attr/textSelectHandle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/xyz_button" />
```

the ImageView is going to align its left edge with the left edge of view with id xyz_button so, in this case, view with id xyz_button is anchor view.

Answer (score 3):

In relative layout or in any view group, if we use so many attributes to position our view like:

`android:layout_alignTop`, `android:layout_alignBottom` etc.

In those attributes, we provide a view's id to align our view. Like:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/add_btn"
```

So, this given view is called as Anchor View. Here view with id `addBtnView` is our **Anchor View**.

Comment: Same can be said about ConstraintLayout